# unsafe-hashes an alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy, owasp

I need to run the following inline script to inject some `Thymeleaf` model variables into a `javascript` file of mine.

```
  <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var stripePublicKey = /*[[${stripePublicKey}]]*/ null;
    var stripeReturnUrl = /*[[${stripeReturnUrl}]]*/ null;
    var paymentType = /*[[${paymentType}]]*/ null;
    /*]]>*/
  </script>
```

My CSP blocks it because it's just `script-src: 'self'`

I know that I could hash the content of it and allow it in the CSP like: `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-.....'`

Would that solution be safe? I know that if the content changes, I would have to recalculate the hash. But apart from this, is it safe?

Alternatively I could do:

```
  <body>
  <span hidden id="stripePublicKey" th:data="${stripePublicKey}"></span>
  <span hidden id="paymentType" th:data="${paymentType}"></span>
  <span hidden id="stripeReturnUrl" th:data="${stripeReturnUrl}"></span>
```

and in my js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const stripePublicKey = $('#stripePublicKey').attr('data');
    const stripeReturnUrl = $('#stripeReturnUrl').attr('data');
    const paymentType = $('#paymentType').attr('data');
```

.. and use them. But I feel like it's a dirty solution with those hidden tags. But would this be safer?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: another alternative is to have jQuery make an ajax call to get those values directly from the back-end.  In theory not allowing in-line scripts should be safer than allowing them. If you only allow scripts from your own domain then it gives you a little more security from XSS.  (the attacker would need to upload the script to your server)